# How to assign TWO parents to LaTeX counter?

Tags: environments, koma-script, counters

I am working on a own LaTeX (using KOMA-Script) class, based on `scrartcl`.

The document structure is supposed to provide sections and subsections, as well as own environments (exercises, solutions, examples &c.).

Those environments are to follow in the hierarchy directly after section, IF no subsection is declared and after subsection IF it is declared, respectively.

I am looking for a way to automatically reset the counters of such environments, say the counter `exc` of the exercise-environment, everytime the counters `section` OR `subsection` are changed.

You can find a minimal example here:

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{exc}[section]
%%% HERE OUGHT TO BE SOMETHING LIKE [section, subsection], IF YOU KNOW, WHAT I MEAN 

\newenvironment{exc}%
    % begin
    {\par%
    \refstepcounter{exc}% count
    \ifnumequal{\value{subsection}}{0}% find correct level
        % subsection level
        {\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}%
            {Ex.~\thesection.\theexc}% add to toc on subsection level
          \noindent\mbox{Exercise~\thesection.\theexc}\\[\baselineskip] 
        }%
        % subsubsection level
        {\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}%
            {Ex.~\thesubsection.\theexc}% add to toc on subsubsection level
          \noindent\mbox{Exercise~\thesubsection.\theexc}\\[\baselineskip]
        }%
    }%
    % end
    {\par\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello}

  \begin{exc} Lalala. \end{exc}

  \begin{exc} Lalala. \end{exc}

\section{World}

\subsection{my little world}

  \begin{exc} Lalala. \end{exc}

\subsection{your big life}

 \begin{exc} Lalala. \end{exc} %% HERE'S THE PROBLEM.

\section{Bye!}

 \begin{exc} Lalala. \end{exc}

\end{document} `
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! A counter `\newcounter{foo}[subsection]` *will* be reset both when `section` or `subsection` are incremented.

Comment: @clemens That is true from latex releases 2015/01/01 not older latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes – I probably should have mentioned that…

Comment: @clemens mention it an answer and I'll give you a vote:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In current LaTeX releases (since 2015/01/01) you only need

```
\newcounter{exc}[subsection]
```

and the counter `exc` will be reset when `subsection` is either *stepped* or *reset* itself, i.e., also when `section` or `chapter` are stepped.

---

With older releases you can load the [`chngcntr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package and then do

```
\newcounter{exc}[subsection]
\counterwithin*{exc}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{exc}{section}
```

(Thanks to @egreg for the reminder!)

Comment: And with an older release, `\usepackage{chngcntr}` followed by `\newcounter{exc}[subsection]`, `\counterwithin*{exc}{chapter}` and `\counterwithin*{exc}{section}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! -- I had tried that and it didn't work; probably because I had messed around with the `\section` command's definition... Now it works. -- Cheers to you all! Fabulous website, this!!

Comment: as promised :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :)

Answer (score 2):

Renew the `\subsection` command to reset the counter as well:

```
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{\setcounter{exc}{0}\oldsubsection}
```

Comment: That should not be needed with current latex releases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the info...I didn't know that was the case. Unless there is an objection, I'll keep this answer up as an example of a more general approach.